# How is this code optimized by GCC?

Tags: c, optimization, undefined-behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const int a = 10;
    int *ptr = &a;

    printf("Initial value of a:%d\n", a);

    *ptr = 100;
    printf("Modified value of a: %d\n", a);

    return 0;  
}
```

---

Output (`gcc -O3 const_ptr.c -o const_ptr -save-temps`):

```
 Initial value of a: 10
 Modified value of a: 100
```

I compiled the code with optimizations enabled but until the value of `a` is modified in before the second `printf`, is the code correct for code optimizations?

Comment: what's your question

Comment: Undefined behavior. You're modifying a `const` object.

Comment: Why do you think an optimization setting should change the code behavioer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since the code involves undefined behavior, ANYTHING the compiler does is correct from an optimization standpoint.  It could decide to produce code that does nothing, outputting nothing, or it could decide to just ignore the `const` (essentially what it is doing in your case) and generate code appropriate for that.

Of course, from a quality of implementation issue, a GOOD compiler should tell you that this is illegal, and not do anything actively harmful (like reformatting your drive), but anything is possible.

Comment: when we apply code optimization, weather the compiler allow to change the constant value?

Comment: Assigning the address of a `const int` to an `int*` without a cast is a constraint violation, so a compiler must issue a diagnostic.  If a constraint violation occurs, a conforming implementation could do anything--even run an *entirely different program*.  Such a possibility isn't merely hypothetical.  If e.g. a build tool gives up on producing a new `a.out` because of a constraint violation, but an old `a.out` is left over from some other program, an attempt to run what should be the newly-built program might run the old one instead.